# wrap the Strings and JLabel in JTextPane like "show old message" like Skype

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I am doing a simple chat application that uses MySQL for saving the old message and I am having a problem on how can I wrap the messages with the username and String from the MySQL result just like Skype "show message from yesterday" and when you click it it will show the messages.

This code is for getting the old messages. I dont want this messages to show right aways in the JTextPane. It will only show when "show old messages" is clicked more like a JLabel? a JButton would do.

The question is How can I wrap this to the JLabel or JButton?

```
while(rs.next())
        {

            try {
                final JLabel jp = new JLabel(rs.getString("username")+ "\n");
                jp.setAlignmentY(0.75f);
                jp.addMouseListener(new MouseListener(){

                    @Override
                    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {}

                    @Override
                    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                        Cursor c = Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR);
                        jp.setCursor(c);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                        if(SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton(e)){System.out.print("lawl");}
                        jp.setForeground(Color.BLUE);

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                    jp.setForeground(Color.BLACK);

                    }

                });
                jp.setFont(new Font("arial",Font.BOLD,16));
                jtep.insertComponent(jp);
                sd.insertString(sd.getLength(), ": "+rs.getString("message")+ "\n", MainPanel.sas);
            } catch (BadLocationException e1) {


            }


            MainPanel.count++;}
    } catch (SQLException e) {

    }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please explain "wrap this to the JLabel or JButton"? Just what does this mean?

Comment: You're assuming that everyone knows about _Skype "show message from yesterday"_ whatever that is

Comment: So like a JLabel when you press it, it will show that message that was the result of the MySQL query, but first it will add it to the JLabel the result from the MySQL query

Comment: I am really sorry I cant really explain it will.

Comment: If you need our help, then please keep trying.

Comment: Updated see the Images I posted

Comment: This must be the 3rd time I've added tags (including Swing) to one of your questions.  I was hoping you would take the subtle hint, but seems not.   Please add the most relevant tags to a post.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the example of section folding http://java-sl.com/collapse_area.html

Just modify header and correct mouse sensible area.